# Is there any way to use autocomplete with cmd created by CreateProcessAsUser in windows?

Tags: c, windows, cmd, tabs

According to [this example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/190351/how-to-spawn-console-processes-with-redirected-standard-handles), I spawn a windows cmd.exe with CreateProcessAsUser.

And I redirect its handle to my console application, so my application 
looks just liked a cmd.exe.

My question is, is there any to let my console application to use the 
tab autocompletion, just like the original cmd.exe ?

What it does now when I press the tab key is only to input the "tab blank".

Here is the main code snippet for this example:

```
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  STARTUPINFO si;

  // Set up the start up info struct.
  ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
  si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
  si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  si.hStdOutput = hChildStdOut;
  si.hStdInput  = hChildStdIn;
  si.hStdError  = hChildStdErr;

  if(!CreateProcess(NULL,"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",NULL,NULL,TRUE,
                     CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
     DisplayError("CreateProcess");

  // Set global child process handle to cause threads to exit.
  hChildProcess = pi.hProcess;

  // Close any unnecessary handles.
  if (!CloseHandle(pi.hThread)) DisplayError("CloseHandle");
```

Comment: Is this C code, or C++? They are not the same thing. Which one you're using may affect the answer of some questions.

Comment: Since it's win32 api, I think it is C code. I will edit the tag.

Comment: CMD's autocomplete is implemented via console functions such as `ReadConsoleW`, so it only works when CMD is attached to a console and the process `StandardInput` and `StandardOutput` are console handles. In Windows 10 you should be able to implement this using a pseudoconsole. In this case, to CMD and child processes, it's just a regular console connection, but for the console host on the other end (an instance of conhost.exe), instead of rendering output to and reading input from a window, it renders output to and reads input from UTF-8 streams over pipes provided by your application.